# Method of Undetermined Coefficients in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to use the method of undetermined coefficients to find the general solution of the following equation:

$$y''+2y'+10y=5$$

I know I have to find $y_c$ and $y_p$. For $y_c$, which is the characteristic equation, I got:

$$y_c=e^{-x}(c_1\cos(3x) + c_2\sin(3x))$$

I am not sure what to choose for $y_p$ to derive twice and then plug back into the equation to determine the coefficients of $y_p$

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.stackexchange. In the long term you are encouraged to learn using MathJax and LaTeX typesetting for your questions and answers, but since you seem new I helped you do it this once. There are tutorials both on this site and elsewhere how to use them.

Comment: would choose yp = A be a good yp, so then y'p would be 0 and y"p = 0

Comment: @mathreadler thanks

Comment: That $y_p$ is perfect and you end up with $10 A = 5 \implies A = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: yes thanks I solved that to get y+e^(-x)(c1cos3x + c2sin3x) +1/2

Answer (score 1):

When you have a differential equation such as $$ay'''+by''+cy'+dy=e$$ in which $d$ and $e$ are constants, define $$y=z+\frac ed\implies y'=z'\implies y''=z''\implies y'''=z'''$$ and the equation becomes $$az'''+bz''+cz'+dz=0$$ and you are back to a simpler form.